# Bash check if user exists, if so add number to the username

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

If a username exists I have to add number 2 to that username, and if that username exists too I have to add number 3 to it and so on...
(so if John exists the program has to add John2, and if he exists too, it has to add John3 etc.) Every user I add is then, of course, remembered.

What is the shortest and most simple way to do that in bash?

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: @Cyrus I've tried by making a text file of all the names then checking with grep. But that way of doing it has too many obstacles so I'm asking here.

Comment: Don't you know how to count in bash, how to find out, if a username exists, how to build a loop, how to glue name and number or how to combine those atomic operations into a function/program? And what's about user0 and user1, if user exists?

Comment: @userunknown I do although my knowledge of bash is still very basic. And what I'm looking for here is the best possible solution. If I did it my own way with my knowledge, it would be very messy. User0 and User1 are never added, if User exists, the next one to add is User2, then User3 etc.

Comment: So by now we have 3 conflicting goals: Shortest, most simple and best solution. There is rarely an overlap. Shortest is often pretty cryptic. Best solution is very open to opinion. Most simple depends on knowledge you bring in. I would say that a good solution is fault tolerant, user friendly and well documented so pretty surely not the shortest solution, neither most simple.

Comment: I'm sure one could, using their vast knowledge come up with something that he would consider simple for a beginner to understand and fairly short - the right amount of both therefore making - the best solution (in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `users.txt` is:

```
joe
jimmy
foo
jimmy
bar
jimmy
```

Then you can use awk

```
awk 'cnt[$0]++{$0=$0 cnt[$0]-1} 1' users.txt
```

to produce the output:

```
joe
jimmy
foo
jimmy1
bar
jimmy2
```

Answer (score 0):

Some useful parts:

```
for n in "" {9..11}; do egrep -q "^stefan${n}\b" /etc/passwd && echo "name${n} " || echo "unknown name${n}"; done 
name 
unknown name9
unknown name10
unknown name11
```

Iterate through numbers, look for a (probably generated) username, react differntly if known or unknown, glue name and number.